# How to use non-blocking sockets in ruby's TCPServer class

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcpserver

I'm trying to implement non-blocking sockets in ruby's TCPServer class. I know how to implement non-blocking sockets in ruby's Socket class, but I was wondering if there's a class method, or another way to use them in ruby' TCPServer class? Thanks!

Comment: Both `Socket` and `TCPSocket` are derived from [`BasicSocket`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/socket/rdoc/BasicSocket.html) where all the base functionality resides. That said, if you know how to this with `Socket`, you are all set for `TCPSocket`.

Comment: With all due respect to non-blocking sockets in pure Ruby, the answer should probably be: use EventMachine, iodine or nio4r. They all allow you to use a better (and less buggy) polling system call. In fact, iodine forces you to use `epoll` / `kqueue` over the usual `select`. Note that `select` will break when handling more than 1024 or 2048 connections (depending on the OS), sometimes even sooner.

Comment: @Myst Thanks I'll look into those gems.